# User account activation url not found in Django

Tags: python, django, token

I'm trying to activate a user account in django but I'm getting 404 error, and the error is due to the fact that django is unable to get the activation url. The link I'm trying to assess is `http://127.0.0.1:8000/account/activate/MTU/anfs0f-046aa586847b91da0546e995f34c392a`, but i keep getting url not found.

```
django app urls.py
urlpatterns = [
path('account/', include('account.urls', namespace='account')), 
]
================
urls.py
urlpatterns = [
path('activate/<slug:uidb64>/<slug:token>)/', views.account_activate, name='activate'),
]
```

views.py

```
def account_activate(request, uidb64, token):
    try:
        uid = force_text(urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64))
        user = UserBase.objects.get(pk=uid)
    except(TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, user.DoesNotExist):
        user = None
    if user is not None and account_activation_token.check_token(user, token):
        user.is_active = True
        user.save()
        login(request, user)
        return redirect('account:dashboard')
    else:
        return render(request, 'account/registration/activation_invalid.html')
```

template

```
{% autoescape off %}
Great {{ user.user_name }}!
Please click on the link below to activate your account
http://{{ domain }}{% url 'account:activate' uidb64=uid token=token %}
{% endautoescape %}
```

I have spent a couple of hours trying to figure out where my mistake is but I haven't been able. Please I want some insight on this.

Comment: What url shows browser in address bar? Maybe you created wrong url. Do you really need `http://{{ domain }}` in url? Are you sure it has to be `'account:activate'` - or maybe `'activate'`

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: The link that was generated is `http://127.0.0.1:8000/account/activate/MTU/anfs0f-046aa586847b91da0546e995f34c392a`.

Comment: read my comment again - put in question, not in comment. More people will see it so more people may help you.

Comment: The `http://{{ domain }}` is used to get the domain, in this case I'm using a local server. I'm actually sending activation token through email

Comment: do you test links on the same computer as you run server? `127.0.0.1` will not work from other computer.

Comment: Yes, I'm using the same computer

Comment: I have no idea what is the problem. We can't run it so we can't test it. You can only start with simpler version and check if it will work with `path('activate`,...)` . I assume you it is  `urls.py` in folder with application and you also import it in `urls.py` which is in folder with settings.

Comment: I imported the url in folder with settings.py using the` include` statement. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

i think you should put your app_name in accounts url in top of urlpatterns.

Comment: I added the app_name in to the file where I have the account url, but the issue still remains

Comment: Add a "/" at the end of your url when requesting.